# how do i repair a broken 3gp file

Tags: video, vlc, codec, repair, 3gp

I have a 3gp-video file that is broken: the end of the file is missing.

This happened because the battery of my phone was nearly empty and while the phone was saving the video on the SD-Card it just stopped in the middle.

How can I watch this half video file? It already has 50MB so the most important part of the video should be still there.

I tried several programs like VLC, GOM, Adobe Premiere,...
but none of them can play this file.

I guess that the header of the file contains the allover length somehow and if the length doesen't fit, the players say it is broken. but that's just a guess.

Maybe someone knows, how to replace the header with a fitting new header, for example from another video?

Comment: Perhaps the whole file is still in your phone memory.  Try this: take out the SD card, and see if the phone lists the file.  If so, copy the broken file off of your SD card and delete it from the SD card, and maybe you can try copying it again.

Comment: no not there anymore. i have only the broken file on my computer now